# How to order by custom field id in JQL

Tags: jira, jql

Say I have a custom field named 'Custom Field' with id customfield_1111.

I know I can order in jql

```
project = ID and issueType = Project order by 'Custom Field' asc
```

Is there a way to sort it by id without knowing the field name?

```
project = ID and issueType = "issue type" order by customfield_1111 asc
project = ID and issueType = "issue type" order by getLabel('customfield_1111') asc
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do that.

You can search by Custom Field name or Custom Field ID (i.e. the number that JIRA automatically allocates to an Custom Field).

For you it will be like this:

```
project = ID AND issueType = Bug ORDER BY "cf[CustomFieldID]" ASC
```

where "cf[CustomFieldID]" = "cf[1111]".

For more information about this, please read this [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/advanced-searching-179442050.html)